# How to cut an egg without the yolk sticking to the knife?

Tags: eggs, cutting

I cut a number of eggs for a salad and had most yolks stuck to the knife. The problem, to me, is that the egg falls apart. The yolk is loose and the white as well.

Does anybody know a way to cut the egg without that happening?

Comment: Personally I like a runny yolk for my eggs, even with salad - solves the sticking problem as well. Boil for 8 mins exactly, 8.5 if you keep your eggs in the fridge. :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, hahaha, I also like them a bit runny, but for a salad, I'm sticking with the yolk that sticks to the knife.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the wire egg slicers seem to be free of this problem. Perhaps you could use a wire, or better yet the wire cutting tool that potters use for clay.

Comment: I did notice that it sticks less to the thin part of the blade (the tip).

Comment: I like those dedicated wire egg slicers (something like this: http://www.gifttrap.com/images/lovehate/egg_slicer.jpg) -- they are pretty cheap, they do a good job, and they are also very handy for slicing mushrooms and strawberries into nice, even slices. (I actually bought mine when I was vegan and didn't eat eggs...)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a chef's knife, cut it with a knife that has a thinner profile and a lower amount of surface area. This will decrease the amount of friction created as the blade slides through the yolk, and decrease the sticking. The wire cutters are able to do this because they have an extremely small area actually in contact with the yolk.

Try a boning knife, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I read a recent tip (lifehacker?) about coating your knife with a thin coating of butter or oil to help cut a cake neatly -maybe it would work for eggs. I don't eat hardboiled eggs, so I have no actual real-life opportunities to try this, but it seems like it would work the same.

Comment: I'll give that a try next time :-)

Comment: Interesting idea, someone should try this! I would imagine a little extra oil/fat would only improve the egg itself.